# What kind of visa do I need for a partially paid internship in Spain?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, paperwork, spain

I am an Indian citizen and a Spanish Institute (Instituto de Astrofísica de Canarias) has accepted my research stay proposal for a stay of almost 3 months (less than 90 days). They will be paying me 200 Euros per month, while I will be personally funding the rest of the cost.

When I look up the agency that does the Spanish visa in India ([BLS India](https://india.blsspainvisa.com/)) the only visa categories included are Tourist and Business and I am not sure if my travel falls into either.

I am confused as to what category of visa I need and furthermore what documents I would require for the application.

Comment: Its not exactly 3 moths. Edited to reflect that

Answer (score 1):

While the proposed duration is less than three months, it would seem to be within the long-term visa categories that your partially-paid affiliation with the Institute is covered. Found in the [BLS Useful Links box](https://india.blsspainvisa.com/), select [Long Term Visa Click here for Long Term Visa Application](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/MUMBAI/en/InformacionParaExtranjeros/Documents/09%20WORK%20AND%20TEMPORARY%20RESIDENCE%20VISA%20FOR%20RESEARCH.pdf), and it takes you to the requirements to obtain a temporary residence visa to work and conduct research in Spain.

In addition to the application, passport, photos, police record and medical certificate, you would be expected to include the invitation Instituto de Astrofísica de Canarias which sets forth the purpose, terms, and length of your affiliation with it.